# Firestore Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase so please be gentle. I am making a web app where people can store images on their profile. Images go to Cloud Storage via as described in
upload-files#full_example. After they are uploaded I save the downloadUrl in my real-time db. Users have to authenticate via firebase.

```
login(username: string, password: string): any {
    this.httpStatus.setHttpStatus(true);
    return this.firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
        .then((firebaseUser: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
            this.httpStatus.setHttpStatus(false);
            this.userService.setUser(firebaseUser);
            if (!this.userService.getUser().emailVerified) {
                this.userService.getUser().sendEmailVerification();
            }
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        });
}
```

This is how I upload from client side:

```
uploadFile() {
    this.httpStatus.setHttpStatus(true);
    const file = this.file.nativeElement.files[0];
    const uid = this.userService.getUser().uid;
    const firebase = this.firebaseService.firebase;
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    // Create the file metadata
    const metadata = {
        contentType: file.type
    };
    console.log(file);
    // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
    const uploadTask = storageRef
        .child('userFiles' + '/' + uid + '/' + file.name)
        .put(file, metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.on(
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
        function(snapshot) {
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            this.httpStatus.setHttpStatus(false);
            this.error.emit(error);
        },
        () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                this.httpStatus.setHttpStatus(false);
                this.success.emit({url: downloadURL, name: file.name});
            });
        }
    );
}
```

This is how I save that URL in my DB:

```
async setDocument(req, callback, errorCallback) {
    const url = req.body.url;
    const user = req.body.user;
    const fileName = req.body.name;
    try {
        await this.verify(req.body.token);
        const result = await this.db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('docs')
            .doc(fileName)
            .set({
                url,
                fileName
            });
        callback(result);
    } catch (error) {
        errorCallback(error);
    }
}
```

This is how I return these URLs:

```
async getDocuments(req, callback, errorCallback) {
    const url = req.body.url;
    const user = req.body.user;
    try {
        await this.verifySameUIDOrAccesslevel(
            req.body.token,
            req.body.user.uid,
            5
        );
        const result = await this.db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('docs')
            .get();
        const data = [];
        result.forEach(each => data.push(each.data()));
        callback(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        errorCallback(error);
    }
}
```

This is how the response to the client looks like:

```
[{"url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{{projectId}}.appspot.com/o/userFiles%2FIZxlZnKhQzYEonZf5F6SpMvu1af1%2FNelson_Neves_picuture.gif?alt=media&token=27cce93f-41a3-460b-84e9-4e8b8ceafc41","fileName":"Nelson_Neves_picuture.gif"}]
```

On the profile i have an anchor tag with this URL as src. Which resolves to:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
 }
}
```

I know this has something to do with the "token=222adabc-2bc4-4b07-b57f-60cbf2aa204c" and I just don't understand why some files can be read and others can't.

My rules for storage are simply:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain this token to me and how I can share a permanent URL with my Authenticated users?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with how you are calling download Url. You have to use same file ref url instead of uploadTask ref.

```
this.imageFile.name.substr(this.imageFile.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(this.filePath); <--- here
  this.task = this.storage.upload(this.filePath, this.imageFile);
  this.uploadPercent = this.task.percentageChanges();
  this.task
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL(); <--- here
        this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
          this.imageUrl = url;
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
  return this.uploadPercent;
}
```